# ошибка Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая считывает значения из одного тэга  и вставляет значения в другой тэг. Функция работает корректно, но в консоли появляется ошибка Cannot read property 'value' of undefined  значения pressureName[i].value. проверил через typeof существует ли свойство- typeof пишет "string", опять же и код работает. Подскажите почему выскакивает такая ошибка?

````
```
function convertPressure() {
let convertPressure = document.getElementsByClassName('convertPressure');
let value_pressure = document.getElementsByClassName('pressure');
let pressureName = document.getElementsByClassName('pressureName');
let result = '';

for (let i = 0; i <= pressureName.length; i++){
    console.log(typeof(pressureName[i].value));
    let pressureNamev = pressureName[i].value;
    console.log("значение"+pressureNamev);
switch (pressureNamev) {
    case "Па": result = value_pressure[i].value/1;
    console.log(pressureName[i].value);
        convertPressure[i].innerHTML = result;
        break;
    case "бар": result = Math.round(value_pressure[i].value/0.00001);
        convertPressure[i].innerHTML = result;
        break;
    case "кгс/см2": result = Math.round(value_pressure[i].value/0.0000101972);
        convertPressure[i].innerHTML = result;
        break;
    case "мм рт. ст.": result = Math.round(value_pressure[i].value/0.00750064);
        convertPressure[i].innerHTML = result;
        break;
    case "мм вод. ст.": result = Math.round(value_pressure[i].value/0.101972);
        convertPressure[i].innerHTML = result;
        break;
}

}


}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вылезаете за границу массива - последний индех должен быть `pressureName.length - 1`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < pressureName.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Точно! Помогло! Огромное спасибо! Буду знать!

Comment: @АлексейСуржанский Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.